# ¿Por qué el contenido que ingreso en mi modal no aparece en mi h1?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap

Lo que intento hacer es que el texto que ingrese en mi modal aparezca en mi h1 de la siguiente manera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero en lugar de eso me aparece de esta otra manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cual es el problema? Aquí les dejo mi código:
Esto es HTML

```
<p>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#nombralo">Nombra esta foto</button>
    <div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="nombralo">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title">Dale nombre a esta foto</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <form>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="message-text" class="control-label">Nombra la foto:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="message-text">
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="aceptar">Aceptar</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <h1></h1>
</p>
```

Y esto es lo de Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#aceptar").click(function () {
    $("#message-text").appendTo("h1");
  })
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que estás haciendo en tu código es meter el `<input>` dentro del `<h1>` y es por ello que te muestra el `<input>`.

Por otra parte, cuando haces `.appendTo("h1")` te anexará lo que le indicas a todas las etiquetas `<h1>`. Si esto no es lo que quieres podrías usar el `id` del elemento html que quieras actualizar.

En la parte de javascript prueba a cambiar

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#aceptar").click(function () {
    $("#message-text").appendTo("h1");
  })
});
```

Por

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#aceptar").click(function () {
    var txt = $("#message-text").val()
    $("<span>"+txt+"</span>").appendTo("id_dentro_de_h1");
  })
});
```

Y en la parte HTML, cambia la línea del `<h1>` de esto:

```
<h1></h1>
```

a esto:

```
<h1 id="id_dentro_de_h1"></h1>
```

donde `id_dentro_de_h1` debería ser el identificador que consideres para ese `<h1>` concreto.

Comment: Me funciono muy bien, muchas gracias!!!

Comment: Disculpa, todo esta muy bien pero me gustaria que lo que escribo en mi modal se ponga solamente en un h1, no en todos los h1 (porque tengo mas modals y mas h1 abajo) se que se podria usar "this" pero no sabria en que parte ponerlo, podrias ayudarme?

Comment: He actualizado la respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

y si le borras  `<p>`del inicio y `</p>`del final ?

Comment: acabo de intentarlo y no me funcionó